# How can I check the content of set of immutable pair of strings in java?

Tags: java, set

I have the following method:

```
public Set<ImmutablePair<String, String>> getUserSpecs() {
    Set<ImmutablePair<String, String>> result = new TreeSet<>();
    getSpecsMap().values().forEach(set -> {
        set.stream().filter(s -> s.getRight()).map(s -> new 
        ImmutablePair(s.getLeft(), s.getMiddle())).forEach(pair -> result.add(pair));
    });

    return result;
}
```

How can I print in the console its content (every element from there)?

Comment: `System.out.println(result)`?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can achieve the console output with use above notion of lambda expressions as per your code. These can be embedded in your code of iteration of set

> forEach(System.out::println);
>
> item -> System.out.println(item)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stream API's peek intermediate operation for that in the stream chain:

```
.peek(pair -> System.out.println(pair)).forEach...
```